# Index of the minimum difference of the elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector `v`. I would like to find the index  of the minimum difference of the elements of a vector `v`  which is less that 1e-2. How can I get the index?

```
    v = c(0.0002873771, 0.0006478544, 0.0092186701, 0.0267084167, 
        0.0457307072 , 0.3176459806)
    D = abs(diff(v)) < 1e-2
```

I want to get that the index = 1 not 1 and 2, just the minimum one.
If we have this vector

```
    v = c( 0.01144003, 0.04644231, 0.05527114, 0.31680614)
    D = abs(diff(v)) < 1e-2
    index = which.min(abs(diff(v)) < 1e-2 )
```

It give me the index = =  1 but actually my desire index is 2 not 1.

Comment: Do you want the minimum index of true values in `D`, or the (first) index of the true value in `D` that has the minimum `abs(diff)`?

Comment: The index of the true value in D that has the minimum abs(diff) not the fisrt one.

Comment: the issue is that the difference loses you one observation. So `v` is 6 elements long, and D is `abs(diff(v))` is only five elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the minimum absolute difference is less than your tolerance, which.min is the correct function, and there is no need for `D`.

```
> which.min(abs(diff(v)))
[1] 1
```

This code, in your edited question:

```
index = which.min(abs(diff(v)) < 1e-2 )
```

is taking the which.min of a logical vector.  Not what you intend.  This is what you (probably) want:

```
v = c( 0.01144003, 0.04644231, 0.05527114, 0.31680614)
> which.min(abs(diff(v)))
[1] 2
```

To actually check for your tolerance, you can use `any` and `if`.  Here, I assume you want `NA` to be returned if all differences exceed your tolerance:

```
min.difference.index <- if (any(abs(diff(v)) < 1e-2)) which.min(abs(diff(v))) else NA
```

Comment: Its correct but if the minimun difference was the second one , by this code its give the fist minimum diff not the second one.

Comment: Re-reading the question, you only want these 'small' differences, but then you want the minimum diff of these?

Comment: could you please see my othe example which I have problem to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the process of differencing costs you one observation.

see:

```
length(v) == length(D)
[1] FALSE
```

and:

```
length(v) == length(D) + 1
[1] TRUE
```

So your index numbers are always one 'too low' -- as they refer to the position in the shorter 'difference' object. If you wish to index with this vector, use:

```
v[which.min(abs(diff(v))) + 1]
```

or:

```
Idx <- which.min(abs(diff(v))) + 1
v[Idx]
```